# How many Area 51 sites failed the beta phase?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase

Has any Area 51 proposal failed the beta phase and been closed? If so, is there a list of them?

Comment: Looks like http://beer.stackexchange.com/ is also on its way down.

Comment: @ShadowWizard There is a general feeling of doom on the Beer Meta, but I haven't seen an actual announcement of closure. SE could try merging it with Homebrew... Computer Graphics is closing, btw.

Comment: Are there any [efforts to not just lose all the content from the sites that don't survive beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359676/how-can-we-preserve-area51-sites-that-get-closed-during-the-beta)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can find closed sites by [searching for `site:area51.stackexchange.com "didn't have enough activity during the beta, and has been closed"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aarea51.stackexchange.com+%22didn%27t+have+enough+activity+during+the+beta%2C+and+has+been+closed%22).

- [3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics)
- [Arduino](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino) (though [this version is going strong](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino))
- [Artificial Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence)<sup>2</sup>
- [Astronomy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51/astronomy)<sup>3</sup>
- [Atheism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism)
- [Digital Fabrication](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850/digital-fabrication)
- [Digital Preservation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39787/digital-preservation)
- [Economics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics)<sup>3</sup>
- [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets)<sup>1</sup>
- [Embedded Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-systems)
- [Firearms](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/164/firearms)<sup>3</sup>
- [Game of Go](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go)
- [Gamification](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44478/gamification)
- [Healthcare IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it)<sup>3</sup>
- [How Things Work](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15025/how-things-work)
- [Libraries & Information Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12432/libraries-information-science)
- [Literature](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature)<sup>3</sup>
- [Machine Learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41738/machine-learning)
- [Mental Fitness](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51461/mental-fitness)
- [Personal Manufacturing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22246/personal-manufacturing)
- [Personal Productivity](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity/5054)
- [Relationships and Dating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating)
- [Sexuality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/sexuality)
- [Startup Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business)
- [Theoretical Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics)<sup>3</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup> ["Pruning season"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/)</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> ["No Artificial Intelligence in Area 51"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/)</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> ["When a Site Grows Quiet"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/)</sup>

Comment: @ShadowWizard - odd that *Relationships and Dating* did not show up in the Google search (unless it is outside my "Google bubble"!).

Comment: @Wikis for some reason the proposal on Area51 for R&D does not have the banner like the others, and no data dump, maybe because it was closed rather quickly or did not reach public beta.

Answer (score 36):

[Atheism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism) closed. Ironically, not enough people believed in it.

Comment: hahahaha oh, the irony.

Comment: @Petruza: actually, they *["simply ran out of questions"](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/why-will-this-dupe-of-atheism-succeed-where-the-former-beta-failed/3881#3881)*, to be fair. :)

Comment: That's hilarious, being an atheist, I fully believe that... what type of questions would you even ask? :P

Comment: @Jakub: you can check out the link I provided to view a data dump of all the questions.

Answer (score 14):

There's been two that I know of, [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) and [Artificial Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence). There were blog posts about both, [Pruning season](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/) and [No Artificial Intelligence in Area 51](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/). I don't think there is a complete list, since it's pretty rare

Answer (score 6):

Artificial Intelligence [has failed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/). So has [Electronic Gadgets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/).

It's [not looking good](http://meta.atheism.stackexchange.com/questions/369/is-the-site-likely-to-get-out-of-beta) for Atheism either.